# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: Long boot time, Dummy Output, and no Brightness Setting

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have an HP Envy computer that is dual-booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. My computer was working fine until suddenly, several problems came up.

First, the booting. The boot terminal would alternate between:

`(1 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7d7eaf7\x2d6079\x2d474e\x2db3d4\x2d2974f9658f89.device`

and:

`(2 of 2) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7816\x2dF20B.device`

for 1 min and 30 sec. After waiting for that time, the terminal outputs:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b7d7eaf7\x2d6079\x2d474e\x2db3d4\x2d2974f9658f89.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/b7d7eaf7-6079-474e-b3d4-2974f9658f89.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swap.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-7816\x2dF20B.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/7816-F20B.
```

and after that, it outputs other lines that seem normal, with some of them having the `[  OK  ]` tag.

It then puts me in emergency mode. I type in `exit` to do default booting. Then, I have to wait another 1 min and 30 sec to get to the log-in screen. After logging in, I find out that my sound card is shown as "Dummy Output" and that I can't adjust the brightness.

Sometimes when I restart the computer, an alternative boot terminal shows up with `A start job is running for /boot/efi`. After 1 min and 30 sec, I get to the log-in screen, but my mousepad and keyboard would no longer work. If I restart and get the other boot screen, I can proceed with my mousepad and keyboard intact.

I went into recovery mode and fixed all broken packages, but it still wouldn't fix the problem.

Update: On some rare occasions after rebooting the computer a few times, it will boot up normally without any issues, with the volume and brightness setting restored. However, if I reboot the computer again, the same problem reoccurs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related with a corruption in EFI partition caused by a Windows update. I found this workaround.

Edit fstab, by running

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

Comment out the line that is related with EFI by adding `#`  (with space) to the beginning of the corresponding line. It should include something like /boot/efi. Save and close fstab, reboot the computer. The system should boot fast as it will not try to mount the EFI partition.

Comment: You actually don’t need a space after the # - everything after the # is ignored, space or not.